# How to timeout in Python on windows without multithreading?

Tags: python, windows

I am using Python 3.7.3 on Windows 10 Pro and I need to timeout a program if it gets hung up trying to connect to a printer for too long. Is there a way I can do this without using multiple threads?

Comment: how are you connection to the printer? usually such client libs have a `timeout` parameter of their own already implemented

Comment: @Adam.Er8 we're using the socket library and connecting over a TCP/IP connection. As far as I know there isn't a build in `timeout` function in anything we are using

Comment: I believe this should actually work: https://docs.python.org/3/library/socket.html#socket.socket.settimeout

Comment: @Adam.Er8 the issue isn't checking if we can connect to the printer, we have a .jar file that we embedded in the python code and run to get the status of the printer and it really slows things down to do that every time we try to print a label, so we are trying to implement a timeout that only runs that .jar file if the current label doesn't finish printing after a few seconds.

Comment: @Adam.Er8 in other words, the socket connection is not the thing we need to time out

Comment: OK, then I really think the best solution is to use multi-threading, (e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/492519/timeout-on-a-function-call ), I'm not sure if there's a cleaner solution

Comment: @Adam.Er8 I'm running windows, i cant use anything from the 'signal' package

Comment: look at the 2 other answers